# Find formula of a linear transformation given its matrix with respect to ordered bases

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If the matrix corresponding to a linear transformation $T:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$, with respect to standard ordered basis of $\Bbb R^2$, i.e., $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$, for both the domain and co-domain,is \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 4 \end{bmatrix}.
What is the formula for linear transformation $T$?

I tried following:
as we know that $T(v)=Av$
$$T(\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ y\end{bmatrix})=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 4 \end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 2x+3y \\ 1x+4y \end{bmatrix}$$
So formula for given linear transformation would be: $T(x,y)=(2x+3y,1x+4y)$. But my solution is wrong. I don't know why???

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please show your work/attempts. If you do not do this your question will likely be closed.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I have included my work in the image attached.https://i.stack.imgur.com/sivGG.png

Comment: It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You solution is wrong because $\Bbb R^2=\{(x,y)\vert x,y\in\Bbb R\}$. Thus, the linear transformation $T:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ maps ordered pairs to ordered pairs, not column matrices to column matrices.

Since the matrix of $T$ with respect to the standard basis is
$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 4 \end{bmatrix},$$
then
$$T(1,0)=2(1,0)+1(0,1)=(2,1);\\
T(0,1)=3(1,0)+4(0,1)=(3,4).$$
Since $(x,y)=x(1,0)+y(0,1)$, we have
$$T(x,y)=xT(1,0)+yT(0,1)=x(2,1)+y(3,4).$$
Therefore,
$$\boxed{T(x,y)=(2x+3y,1x+4y)}.$$